# What is the right way of managing dependencies in yeoman app which are not exist in bower?

Tags: yeoman

I'm using yeoman and it's a great tool. It uses bower for managing dependencies and it assumes you would have all dependencies listed in bower file and then install it in `bower_components` folder and link them from the your html. But I didn't find any info about the case when some of project dependencies(js or css) are not under bower (for example, it could be some commercial libraries, purchased by developer and not available in open source). How should I manage this case? Let's assume general `yeoman webapp` template. Where should I store js and css from the libraries which are not under bower?

Answer (score 0):

If the dependency you want to add to your project is not managed by Bower, then it should be separate from your "bower_components" dir.  That directory should only have things that Bower controls: i.e., things installed with this command:

```
bower install
```

You should create a "lib" dir that has third party components that you install and update manually.

```
app/
├--bower_components/
│  └--angular/
└--src/
   └--css/
   └--js/
   └--lib/
      ├--manual_dependency/
      └--other_dependency/
```